# Annotating parameters with non-type objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

I'm developing a framework that takes python functions and converts them to containerized programs.
I need a way to annotate function parameters with some extended information.
I started using Python's "parameter annotations"/"type hints" for this purpose.
However I hear some rumors that in the future annotations that are not types will become illegal. Is that true?
Is it OK for my framework to use non-type objects in annotations?

```py
def my_func(
    param1: 'foo',
    param2: 'foo bar',
    param3: {'a' : 1},
):
    pass
```

Comment: Where do you hear such rumors? By the way `param1: 'foo'` is currently used as a [forward reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) per PEP-484.

Comment: Strictly speaking, things like `typing.List` are already non-type objects. The question is, will using annotations that don't conform to PEP-484 continue to be accepted?

Comment: I guess, the rumor is more along the lines of `eval(annotation_literal)` must work.

Comment: You may be interested in [PEP 593](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0593/), which gives you a way of creating annotations that contain a mixture of both type hints and other arbitrary expression. This gives you a way of attaching arbitrary metadata to annotations while still keeping the code compatible with PEP 484 type checkers.

Answer (score 2):

When PEP-484 was released, it specifically allowed continued use of function annotations for whatever purpose you like:

> Note that this PEP still explicitly does NOT prevent other uses of annotations, nor does it require (or forbid) any particular processing of annotations, even when they conform to this specification. It simply enables better coordination, as PEP 333 did for web frameworks.

PEP-484 simply standardizes what type hints should look like, if annotations are used for hinting.

---

PEP-563, however, contains a note which seems to contradict or override this:

> #### Non-typing usage of annotations
>
> While annotations are still available
> for arbitrary use besides type checking, it is worth mentioning that
> the design of this PEP, as well as its precursors (PEP 484 and PEP
> 526), is predominantly motivated by the type hinting use case.
>
> In Python 3.8 PEP 484 will graduate from provisional status. Other
> enhancements to the Python programming language like PEP 544, PEP 557,
> or PEP 560, are already being built on this basis as they depend on
> type annotations and the typing module as defined by PEP 484. In fact,
> the reason PEP 484 is staying provisional in Python 3.7 is to enable
> rapid evolution for another release cycle that some of the
> aforementioned enhancements require.
>
> With this in mind, **uses for annotations incompatible with the
> aforementioned PEPs should be considered deprecated.**

I don't see any PEPs after 563 that make mention of *function* annotations, though, only variable annotations.

---

I would ***tentatively*** suggest that you can continue to use function annotations as you like, as long as you are aware that such use is incompatible with tools like `mypy`.

The fact that `from __future__ import annotations` stops the evaluation of annotations and treats them as raw strings (which will becomes the default behavior in Python 4) suggests that if you stick to strings *now*, there will continue to be no run-time consequences of using non-type-hint annotations. (That is, don't rely on your annotations to actually be evaluated.)